# Storing in a List and a Nested List in R

Tags: r, list, loops

Storing in a list and a nested list seems to have different restrictions, but I don't understand why.

If I want to store 100 random generated numbers to list `year1972`,  I have no problem.

```
 year1972<-list()
 set.seed(1234)
 year1972<-rnorm(100)
```

With this code, I can store `rnorm` generated 100 numbers without any problem.

But if I create a nested list like following.

```
pars<-list(year1972=list(), year1974=list())
set.seed(1234)
pars[1]<-rnorm(100)
```

Then I get following error message.

```
Warning message:
In pars[1] <- rnorm(100) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Why do I see this error message? How can I store these 100 values as a normal list?

I need a nested list structure because I want these nested lists to use in a loop. I want to store 19 different lists of random generated numbers. To store these random generated numbers as a list, the only way I thought is nested list and call them as `pars[i]` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to do `pars[[1]]` or `pars[[2]]`. Or equivalently:

```
pars$year1972 <- rnorm(100)
```